# Downloading files in Python 3.x using wget.download results in connection timed out error, why?

Tags: python-3.x, wget

Context: I have a script that basically parses the email body and fetches for URLs with a specific prefix. The script then downloads a file from the URL and hits a REST api at backend with the downloaded contents.

Now, it has successfully identified the URL but the downloading file step is failing. It's leading to a connection timed out error. `Error : <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>`

We have proxy-ied this new host but not sure if that's the reason behind this. To download the file I'm using `wget.download (URL, location)` function.

When I copy the same URL into browser and hit enter, it downloads the file.

How can I make this right?

Comment: you really should give a [minuimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise there is no way to narrow down what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
wget.download (URL, location)
```

This suggest you are using [`wget` python package](https://pypi.org/project/wget/) as opposed to GNU wget. Observe that last version was published Oct 22, 2015. Therefore I suggest you using [`urllib.request.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) from standard library instead, it is simple to use - just provide URL and filename, e.g.

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.example.com", "example.html")
```

Comment: Will try this. I kept my SRE in the loop, so his reason was the nginx couldn't follow the redirection and that's why it didn't download the file.